# Как обойти 503 BS4 python

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Каким образом можно обойти 503 с BS4

Selenium долго работает, поэтому не хотелось бы его использовать

[сайт для запроса](https://mangalib.me/)

подмена user-agent не помогла

в коде цикла нет, эта ошибка прилетает с первого запроса

```py
header = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}
```